# Storing large number of mapsets with many raster maps

Tags: raster, grass-gis, file-formats, osx

OS X El Capitan, GRASS GIS 7.0.1

I have a location with about 530 read-only mapsets with each about 2600 raster maps (plus PERMANENT and one link to a read-write mapset), overall 11.255.481 raster maps and about 181 GB.

What is the best way of storing these in a space efficient way and to
have them accessible read-only?

I have them at the moment in a grass 
database and thought of putting these into a squashfs which should
work (tried with a subset and it was nice - mounting fast, space efficient), but after two days of compressing (and only having compressed
30% - slow speed presumably due to huge number of files) I gave up.

I would like to avoid having to install postgresql as I tried it before
(several years ago) and given up due to it's complexity.

I will analyse the maps in R, so any storage backend which I can use
From R and GRASS would be OK.

Any suggestions?

---

**ADDED INFO**

**Number of Files**   : 11.604.844  (`find . -type f | wc -l`)

**Size of all Files** : 181G   (`du -sch ./*`)

One timing example:

```
01:39:24 /Volumes/simASM$ time mksquashfs ./simASM.Outeniqua.Random.Outeniqua_2_0.Outeniqua.41719.* ~/tmp/simASM.squashfs
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 8 processors
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /Users/rainerkrug/tmp/simASM.squashfs, block size 131072.
[=======================================================================================================================================================================================|] 92263/92263 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
    compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, no xattrs
    duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 365271.48 Kbytes (356.71 Mbytes)
    50.25% of uncompressed filesystem size (726846.67 Kbytes)
Inode table size 801639 bytes (782.85 Kbytes)
    20.23% of uncompressed inode table size (3962401 bytes)
Directory table size 617819 bytes (603.34 Kbytes)
    20.52% of uncompressed directory table size (3010422 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 84524
Number of inodes 122969
Number of files 110768
Number of fragments 1775
Number of symbolic links  0
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 12201
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 2
Number of uids 1
    rainerkrug (501)
Number of gids 1
    staff (20)

real    2m2.877s
user    1m6.972s
sys 1m57.861s
01:41:31 /Volumes/simASM$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squashfs sounds ideal for this situation.

You mentioned "I have them at the moment in a grass database and thought of putting these into a squashfs which should work (tried with a subset and it was nice - mounting fast, space efficient), but after two days of compressing (and only having compressed 30% - slow speed presumably due to huge number of files) I gave up."

This should not have happened.  Mksquashfs is multi-threaded and should have compressed 1,255,481 files making up 200 GB in less than a couple of hours, especially with a modern processor.

What version of Mksquashfs are you using (mksquashfs -version), and from where? (provided by the distribution or downloaded and compiled yourself).  what Linux distro are you using?

Some older versions of Mksquashfs did have some bugs where they occasionally hung if they hit the right triggers (dependant on dataset, memory and processors).  It may well be you're hitting one of these bugs.

You can download the latest release of Mksquashfs from http://sourceforge.net/projects/squashfs/

The development git tree has the latest bug fixes, and is here:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/squashfs/squashfs-tools.git/

If Mksquashfs appears to have hung, you should always check this with "top" and see how much processor time it is using (%CPU).  If Mksquashfs has hung the processor time will be zero or near to it.  If instead Mksquashfs is processing a large difficult to compress file (which is marked as a probable duplicate and so progress can only be made once the entire file has been checked), Mksquashfs may appear to have hung, but, "top" will normally show Mksquashfs using a significant amount of CPU time.

If you're using Mksquashfs 4.3, then this version has the ability to dump the state of the internal queues to the console.  This feature was added specifically to diagnose reasons for slow running or hangs.

Sending SigQUIT to Mksquashfs twice within one second (hit control-\ twice on the keyboard), will cause the queues to be dumped, e.g.

```
Queue and Cache status dump
===========================
file buffer queue (reader thread -> deflate thread(s))
    Max size 24128, size 0 (EMPTY)
uncompressed fragment queue (reader thread -> fragment thread(s))
    Max size 24128, size 0 (EMPTY)
processed fragment queue (fragment thread(s) -> main thread)
    Max size unlimited, size 5
compressed block queue (deflate thread(s) -> main thread)
    Max size unlimited, size 0 (EMPTY)
uncompressed packed fragment queue (main thread -> fragment deflate thread(s))
    Max size 24128, size 0 (EMPTY)
locked frag queue (compressed frags waiting while multi-block file is written)
    Max size 24128, size 0 (EMPTY)
compressed block queue (main & fragment deflate threads(s) -> writer thread)
    Max size 48256, size 0 (EMPTY)
read cache (uncompressed blocks read by reader thread)
    Max buffers 24128, Current size 8, Maximum historical size 76
block write cache (compressed blocks waiting for the writer thread)
    Max buffers 24128, Current size 281, Used 24,  Free buffers
fragment write cache (compressed fragments waiting for the writer thread)
    Max buffers 24128, Current size 14, Used 0,  Free buffers
fragment cache (frags waiting to be compressed by fragment deflate thread(s))
    Max buffers 24128, Current size 2531, Used 1,  Free buffers
fragment reserve cache (avoids pipeline stall if frag cache full in dup check)
    Max buffers 25, Current size 0, Used 0,  No free buffers
[========================================================================-
```

If the above dump does show Mksquashfs has hung (the dump is probably only fully intelligible by an expert on Mksquashfs, but the key to look for is full or non-empty queues at the start of the pipeline and empty queues at the end of the pipeline, which will indicate a blockage in the middle).

Varying the amount of processors used by the -processors option, or increasing the amount of free memory by the -mem option can often work around hangs.

Altering the block size with the -b option and disabling duplicate checking with the -no-duplicates option can also often work around hangs, as these options change the scheduling and threading behaviour.

e.g.

% mksquashfs blah blah.sqsh -b 1M -mem 2G -processors 1 -no-duplicates

Will use blocks of 1Mbytes, use 2GBytes of memory, only one processor and do no duplicate checking.

There is one potential pathological cause of the slow running of Mksquashfs.  You should try the -no-duplicates option to determine if this is happening.  Duplicate checking is a horrendous destroyer of performance in Mksquashfs.  If a file is determined to be a potential duplicate of files already in the filesystem, each potential duplicate has to be read off disk and compared byte-by-byte.  This is slow.  Imagine the pathological case where the 100,000th file is considered a potential duplicate of 1,000 files already in the filesystem.  Each one has to be read of disk and compared.  Imagine if this happens for the 100,001th file, and for the 100,002nd file, and so on, and by the time the 1,000,000 file is reached it is comparing 10,000 potential duplicates.  Mksquashfs will slowly grind to a halt.

Mksquashfs has an obvious safe-guard to prevent this exponential explosion of the amount of potential duplicates to be compared, it computes a checksum of each file added, and a file is only considered a potential duplicate if both the file length and checksum match.  The likelihood a same length file has the same checksum is very low (by definition a different length file is not a duplicate).  But, you could be hitting the situation where you have 10,000s of files of the same length, and for some reason they generate the same checksum, but are different.  In that case there is nothing to prevent the exponential explosion of duplicates that need to be checked.  I have to say in the almost 15 years Mksquashfs has been available this scenario hasn't happened to my knowledge, but there is a first for everything.

Comment: You are right - it sounds perfect for what I want to do. I am using ```mksquashfs version 4.3 (2014/05/12)``` on OS X El Capitan installed via homebrew. The command I used was (If I am not mistaken, I chose this one because of compression speed) ```mksquashfs ./simASM /Volumes/ASM_Optimization/simASM.squashfs```.

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013); 2,4 GHz Intel Core i7; 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: I added the counted number of files and the size to the question.

Comment: OK, it took about 2 minutes to compress about 700 Mbytes.  Mksquashfs does not slow down with increasing files, and it's performance is  therefore largely linear.  Given this, and assuming the rest of the 181 Gbytes is similar, Mksquashfs should have taken  less than 9 hours to compress ((181/.7)*122)/(60*60).

Comment: Mac OS X is not supported or tested.  You probably have hit some variant behaviour between BSD and Linux which is showing as a hang.

Comment: The free memory calculation on Mac OS X will be wrong, so how much memory does Mksquashfs think it has free?  Low memory causes Mksquashfs to run slower as it limits parallelism, causes data to be refetched from disk, and it execerbates any latent threading issues by causing threads to block more often.  I have edited the question to discuss debugging hangs

Comment: Anything I can do to help pinpointing it? I could try to compress a larger subset and see how long it takes?

Comment: You could try compressing an increasing subset, and discover at which point it hangs.  Hangs are usually caused by a pathological file or sequence of files which triggers unexpected/buggiy scheduling.  But reporting how much memory Mksquashfs uses, and giving the "Queue and Cache" dump when it has hung will give more of a clue what is happening first.  Also knowledge whether any of the suggest workarounds (-processors, -mem, -b, -no-duplicates and -no-fragments options) eliminates the hang will be useful.

Comment: Should I install with homebrew from HEAD?

Comment: Yes, that has the latest fixes.

Comment: OK - I will do this tomorrow. Which settings do you suggest for these tests, and how do I get the "Queue and Cache" dump? But to make it clear, mksquashfs did not crash, it was just crawling along very slowly  - there was definitely progress, and the RAM was not used up (if I remember correctly) as I was still working in the foreground.

Comment: You could also try this port of Squashfs-tools to Mac OS X and BSD https://github.com/vasi/squashfs-tools.  The Queue and Cache dump (as explained in the edited answer) can be got by hitting Control-\ twice within one second.  If Mksquashfs is still running but extremely slowly it is likely it is using too little memory on Mac OS X.  For good performance on modern processors, Mksquashfs should be using at least 512 Mbytes.  You can force Mksquashfs to use say 2Gbytes with the -mem option (i.e. %mksquashfs xxx xx.sqsh -mem 2G)

Comment: Thinking about it, there is one pathological case that could explain the extremely slow running of Mksquashfs.  Using the -no-duplicates option will prevent this from happening, and it is hence the first thing you should try.  Duplicate checking is a horrendous destroyer of performance in Mksquashfs.  As I can't why in this comment due to lack of space, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I have many identical files, but they are all small - a few bytes. So I guess this could be the reason. I have uploaded a larger test run ( https://gist.github.com/rkrug/6ec7f4f9a1a30c609cc8 ) with quite a few "Queue and Cache Dumps". This is without the -no-duplicates. I am just running with the -no-duplicates option and it seems to be ***much*** faster.

Comment: Wow - that was fast: real 8m41.778s
user 25m0.996s
sys 3m51.139s see the gist https://gist.github.com/rkrug/6e9432452f2bc5d2b6ba

Comment: Perfect - squashfs of the whole set in less than 7 hours! Impressive the -no-duplicates option. the detailed ouptut is at https://gist.github.com/rkrug/e72984c0edcbedff4605

Answer (score 1):

As I am on OS X, I created a compressed .dmg (read-only) image which contains

- the mapsets
- a link to ./../grassAnalysis which is a read-write mapset located at the same directory of the mount point

This reduces the several million files to one file (the .dmg) and reduces the space required from 200 GB to around 100 GB. This is not yet ideal, but the approach of putting the location into a compressed read-only image file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux systems (maybe also elsewhere), there is "fuse-zip".

https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip/

"fuse-zip is a FUSE file system to navigate, extract, create and modify ZIP and
ZIP64 archives based on libzip implemented in C++.
With fuse-zip you really can work with ZIP archives as real directories.
Unlike KIO or Gnome VFS, it can be used in any application without
modifications."

Likely you want to use a SSD disk here :) If you are willing to try, please report your findings.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168812/6003

Comment: The problem with these archive mounting approaches is usually that the mounting takes a long time if the archive contains many files, as it is the case here. But it sounds like an option, if the compression ratio is better than 2:1 as I get out of the compressed dmg. I will possibly try it out on a subset of my data.